# Index of an element in a 2D ArrayList Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, 2d

I have a 2D ArrayList (ArrayList within an ArrayList). For instance, I have the following values for it:

```
[res, 0.0]
[print, string]
```

Now, how can I access the index where the value "**res**" occurred?

Comment: your list is holding what? strings?

Comment: `list.get(0).get(0)`.

Comment: No. I have to get the index where res occurred. Its like list.get().get().indexOf("res")
Instance of res could be any value. For example, indexOf(print), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over the list in the list:

```
List<List<String>> dList = new ArrayList<>();
    dList.add(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"));
    dList.add(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"));
    dList.add(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"));
    for (List<String> list : dList) {
        if (list.contains("A")) {
        // todo
        }
    }
```

or use a java8 stream

example:

```
List<List<String>> dList = new ArrayList<>();
    dList.add(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"));
    dList.add(Arrays.asList("f", "t", "j"));
    dList.add(Arrays.asList("g", "4", "h"));

    String a = dList.stream().flatMap(List::stream).filter(xx -> xx.equals("a")).findAny().orElse(null);
    a = dList.stream().flatMap(List::stream).filter(xx -> xx.equalsIgnoreCase("a")).findFirst().orElse(null);
    a = dList.stream().flatMap(List::stream).filter(xx -> xx.equals("h")).findFirst().orElse(null);
```

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for but is there any way, that I can do this without looping? I need to be time efficient in this problem. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: time efficiency is going to be hard, find in a list is a Olog(n), now imagine finding in a list of list, maybe modifying that design can help improving the efficiency....

Answer (score 4):

If `list` is your list, you should be able to find the value "res" with:

```
list.get(0).get(0)
```

For a reference `a[row][col]` to an element of a 2d array, the equivalent reference to an `ArrayList` of `ArrayList`s (or really any `List` of `List`s) will be `list.get(row).get(col)`

Comment: see the comments. This is not what the OP wants

Comment: No. I have to get the index where res occurred. Its like list.get().get().indexOf("res"). Instance of res could be any value. For example, indexOf(print), etc.